# Windows 8 phone Sending email error

Tags: email

My Yahoo email on my Windows 8 (nokia 1320) is having a sending error.  Though the SMTP settings are correct 465, its still showing an error (error code: 80072F30)

I already deleted the account several times and reloaded it using Yahoo mail (1st try) and then Other account (2nd try) but to no avail.  I changed the SMTP settings to 25 as suggested in one of the articles but still to no avail.  Need assistance on this please.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you have the error right? That error code is in the WinInet range (as you might expect for a problem when sending data over the Internet) but it's not a known WinInet error value (it's not in the headers or documented on MSDN).